# magento 1.9 + braintree

Tags: magento, paypal, magento-1.9, braintree

I recently installed the latest Braintree extension on my Magento website and disabled the old Braintree extension. After installing the latest Braintree extension I getting below errors.

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'There has been an issue processing your PayPal payment, please try again.' in /home/user/public_html/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /home/user/public_html/app/code/community/Gene/Braintree/Model/Paymentmethod/Paypal.php(213): Mage::throwException('There has been ...')
#1 /home/user/public_html/app/code/community/Gene/Braintree/Model/Paymentmethod/Paypal.php(395): Gene_Braintree_Model_Paymentmethod_Paypal->_authorize(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment), '125.08', true)
#2 /home/user/public_html/app/code/community/Gene/Braintree/Model/Paymentmethod/Paypal.php(475): Gene_Braintree_Model_Paymentmethod_Paypal->_captureAuthorized(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment), '125.08')
#3 /home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(443): Gene_Braintree_Model_Paymentmethod_Paypal->capture(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment), '125.08')
#4 /home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php(395): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->capture(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice))
#5 /home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(608): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice->capture()
#6 /home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(410): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->_invoice()
#7 /home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(348): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->capture(NULL)
#8 /home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(896): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->place()
#9 /home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(1114): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->_placePayment()
#10 [internal function]: Mage_Sales_Model_Order->place()
#11 /home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(105): call_user_func(Array)
#12 /home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(159): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->_runCallbacks()
#13 /home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(189): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->save()
#14 /home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(249): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitOrder()
#15 /home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php(815): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitAll()
#16 /home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(599): Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage->saveOrder()
#17 /home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->saveOrderAction()
#18 /home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveOrder')
#19 /home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#20 /home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#21 /home/user/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#22 /home/user/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'website')
#23 {main}
```

Php version is 5.6.

Answer (score 0):

Magento 1.x deprecated and almost at the countdown of its end of life, there is no support for it; please use a supported platform